# serverless rate is working but cron is not working

Tags: cron, serverless-framework

In serverless.yml

```
functions:
  cron:
    handler: schedule/handler.run
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(28 10 15 * ? *)
          enabled: true
```

I want to get this function is working at 10:28 of 15th every month with UTC.

When `rate(1 minute)` instead of `cron`, it is worked well.

Plugin: `serverless-offline-scheduler`

I want to know that whether serverless supports `cron` with exact time.

If someone can fix this error, please let me know.

Comment: Are you able to see the trigger in the AWS console? Your configuration looks good, bar the fact that you don't need to have `enabled` set to `true` as thats the default.

Comment: I able to see the trigger. I have tested without `enabled`.

Comment: If you can see it in the trigger list with the time you set then its not really a serverless configuration issue.

Comment: Well, how to fix that ?  I want to get the function running at  the time I set

Comment: If the trigger is set at the time you want I would expect that its working but you haven't observed that its working since its once a month...

Comment: I have configured the set time as the time before to reach. But it was not working.   eg, current UTC time -  `10:22:00`  , set time like as `cron(23 10 * * ? *)`

Comment: UTC as of now is 12:21 pm.

Comment: Yeah! I know that , just only sample.

Comment: @Alex It is running at localTime. Thanks you for discussion